# Finding dy/dx given x = 1

Tags: calculus

I want to find $\frac {dy}{dx}$ given $x=1$, if $y = \sqrt{1 + u^2}$ and $u = \frac{x+1}{2x+1}$.

I have tried differentiating y then inserting u into y prime, then plugging in the given x value, though I always get the answer of $\frac{2\sqrt{13}}{13}$, though this does not appear to be the right way of solving this. I may be overlooking something though any help is appreciated.

Comment: Use chain rule: $\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{dy}{du}\frac{du}{dx}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the **chain rule**,

$$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{dy}{du}\cdot \frac{du}{dx} = u\sqrt{1+u^2} \ \cdot-\frac{1}{(2x+1)^2} $$

Now when $x = 1$, we get that $u = \frac{2}{3}$

So just plug everything in.